# Applying Generating Function Approach to a $M/E_r/1$ queue

Tags: calculus, generating-functions, moment-generating-functions, queueing-theory

(This question is about Exercise 27 on page 55 from [these lecture notes](http://www.win.tue.nl/~iadan/queueing.pdf).)

We consider a $M/E_r/1$ queue with arrival rate $\lambda$ and mean service time $r/\mu$. We let $P(z):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}p_nz^n$ be the generating function of the probabilities $p_n$. We assume that the occupation rate $\rho=\lambda \cdot r/\mu$ is smaller than 1.

From Exercise (i), we know that 
$$
P(z)(\lambda+\mu) - p_0\mu = P(z)\lambda z^r + (P(z) - p_0)\mu z^{-1}, \tag{$\dagger$}
$$
but now **we need to show that $P(z)$ is given by** 
$$
P(z) = \frac{(1-\rho)\mu}{\mu-\lambda(z^r+z^{r-1}+\dots+z)}. \tag{$\ddagger$}
$$

I rewrited $(\dagger)$, which yields
$$
P(z) = \frac{p_0\mu(1-z^{-1})}{\lambda(1-z^r)+\mu(1-z^{-1})},
$$
but from there on, I couldn't find a way to rewrite $P(z)$ in such a way that it resembles $(\ddagger)$.

Also, plugging $(\ddagger)$ into $(\dagger)$ did not yield any results.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

From your last identity giving $P(z)$, for $z\neq1$, you may write
$$
\begin{align}
P(z) &= \frac{p_0\mu(1-z^{-1})}{\lambda(1-z^r)+\mu(1-z^{-1})}\\\\
&=\frac{p_0\mu}{\mu+\lambda\dfrac{1-z^r\:}{1-z^{-1}}}\\\\
&=\frac{p_0\mu}{\mu-\lambda z\dfrac{1-z^r}{1-z}}\\\\
&=\frac{p_0\mu}{\mu-\lambda z\left(1+z+\ldots+z^{r-1} \right)}\\\\
&=\frac{p_0\mu}{\mu-\lambda \left(z+\ldots+z^{r-1}+z^{r} \right)}
\end{align}
$$ and since $p_0=1-\rho$, you then obtain the desired result $(\ddagger)$, where we have used the identiy
$$
1+x+\ldots+x^{n-1}=\frac{1-x^{n}}{1-x}, \quad x\neq1,\,n=1,2,\ldots. 
$$

Comment: Just logged it and saw your answer; I found your solution out myself the day after I posted this, but thanks for your efforts! :-)

Comment: @Ghostface You are welcome. You can accept my answer if you want. Thanks!